# Wordpress - Redirect in an Admin Page

Tags: wordpress

I have a menu item I created called 'View Certificates' and a sub menu item called 'Add Certificates'. The Add Certificates page is just a file upload page. After the file uploads successfully, I want it to redirect back to the 'View Certificates' page.

All my code is in the functions.php file. How do I go about doing this redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_redirect` is a function which helps you to redirect 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

& you can run it in conditions with 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: hm, ive tried that and it doesn;t seem to be doing anything.  Could you provide an example?